# Why is the for loop function returning the else-code instead of entering the if-true-code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I created a for loop to return a certain "intentname" variable out of an array of objects (see code snippet 1 below). The wanted result is that it returns the second object (where nodename1 === "Frage"). Unfortunately it returns the else statement, which is "" (see code snippet 2 below).

Code snippet 1: Here is my array of objects:

```
0: {intentname: "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/a0a95fa7-a676-417e-b121-23f988cc492c", nodename1: "Startpunkt"}
1: {intentname: "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/89eca4bc-272f-4080-b7b1-9b8e76188826", nodename1: "Frage"}
2: {intentname: "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/34e621de-e110-4afb-80e0-1226605b2430", nodename1: "Feedback"}
3: {intentname: "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/eeb12d03-d763-4547-a5aa-b8a3f1d1a944", nodename1: "Tipp"}
4: {intentname: "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/b667fae9-d059-40d7-a832-c7e617a1fa80", nodename1: "Frage"}
5: {intentname: "projects/myteachingbot-arxmxd/agent/intents/a0a95fa7-a676-417e-b121-23f988cc492c", nodename1: "Startpunkt"}
```

Code snippet 2: Here is the intentname() function with the for loop:

```
 const intentname = () => {
          for (let i = 0; i < intent.length; i++) {
            console.log(intent[0]);
            console.log(intent[i].nodename1);
            if (intent[0] != undefined && intent[i].nodename1 === "Frage") {
              const intentname3 = intent[i].intentname;
              console.log(intent[i].intentname);
              return intentname3;
            } else {
              return "";
            }
          }
        };
```

Comment: Just go through your script. The first element doesn't fulfill the condition hence it will end in the `else` branch. In there there's a `return` which will stop the execution of the function and "return" a value. Move the `return ""` after the `for` loop and remove the `else` branch.

Comment: _"The [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) statement **ends function execution** and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller."_

Comment: Perfect explanation, now It works like a charm :). Thanks @Andreas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop is not running more than once because you're using **return**. It returns from the function after running the first iteration or checking through `intent[0]`

Refactor your code like this

```js
const intentname = () =>{
 for (let i = 0; i < intent.length; i++) {
    if (intent[0] != undefined && intent[i].nodename1 === "Frage") {
      const intentname3 = intent[i].intentname;
      console.log(intent[i].intentname);
      return intentname3;
    }
  }
  return "";
}
```